# why there is parentheses next to the route's optional parameter

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to React. Just a question on BrowserRouter(Router).

I saw some code as below:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

...
<Switch>
    {routes.map(r =>
        <Route key={r.url}
            path={`/:datatype(${r.datatype})/:mode?/:id?`}
            component={xxx} />
    )}
    <Redirect to={xxx} />
</Switch>
```

Why there is parentheses next to the optional datatype parameter as:

```
`/:datatype("product")/:mode?/:id?`    // let's say r.datatype is a string of "products"
```

[Full source code on GitHub](https://github.com/Apress/pro-react-16/blob/master/23%20-%20REST%20Web%20Services/productapp/src/Selector.js)

Comment: which parantheses you are talking about `( )` or `{ }`?

Comment: @AbhinavKinagi   it is `( )`, why the author add this?

Answer (score 2):

The `:datatype(${r.datatype})` is a [custom match](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#custom-match-parameters) parameter. `Route` is considered matched only when the `datatype` param matches the regexp in `r.datatype`. In your example, the regexp is a string `"product"`, which requires an exact match.

To test it out, try this [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/). Using the route:

```
/:datatype(product)/:mode?/:id
```

- for path `/product/random/123`, it returns a match with the datatype evaluated as `product`.
- for path `/blog/random/123`, it will be a no-match.

React Router matches path using [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0).

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to put parentheses on the route, you can pass parameter just use like this.

I hope it's helpful.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/editcategory/:id"
      render={props => {
        return <EditCategory {...props} />
      }}
    />      
  </Switch>
<BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: but why the author of the code put parentheses? there must be a reason